# No module named django urls for any django-admin command

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble running Django on my company's server. When I try to start a project, like `django-admin startproject newproject`, it gives me:

```
File "/opt/packages/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
from django.urls import set_script_prefix
ImportError: No module named urls
```

When I run python and `import django; django.VERSION`, I get (1, 10, 2, u'final', 0). (I recently downgraded to 1.9.5 to match my company's version).

And of course the company runs 1.9.5 from which I checked from pip list. Shouldn't I get 1.9.5 also when I call for the version in python?

Here is my profile also:

```
python='/opt/packages/anaconda/bin/python'
export PATH=/opt/packages/anaconda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/packages/anaconda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export TCL_LIBRARY=/opt/packages/anaconda/lib/tcl8.5
```

Comment: If VERSION is reporting 1.10, then you didn't successfully downgrade.

Comment: `pip uninstall django` and then reinstall the right version